# Sending an image from client to server via sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-imaging-library

I made a TCP server and client and when the server asks for a command and receives "screenshot" the client will get that data and send over an image as an byte object, however when I try todo .frombytes() and download it and display it it gives me an error which is "not enough image data".

i've tried increasing the buffer to download it.

Server

```py
import socket
from PIL import Image


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.clients = []

    def start(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((self.host, self.port))

        # backlog == how many connections we can have
        server.listen(1)

        while True:
            client, addr = server.accept()

            # Send our command to the client
            message = input("What is your command? ")
            client.send(message.encode(encoding="utf-8"))

            # Receive our data and check what to do with it.
            succesful_screenshot = client.recv(4096).decode(encoding="utf-8")
            if succesful_screenshot == "returnedScreenshot":
                client.settimeout(5.0)
                screenshot = client.recv(4096)

                img = Image.frombytes(data=screenshot, size=(500, 500), mode="RGB")
                img.show()
                print("hit this")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Server(host='localhost', port=10000).start()
```

Client

```py
import socket
from PIL import ImageGrab


class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def start(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.connect((self.host, self.port))

        while True:
            data = server.recv(4096)
            decoded_data = data.decode(encoding="utf-8")
            if decoded_data == "screenshot":
                # If we receive a string from the server which equals "screenshot" then we grab a screenshot
                # We turn that screenshot into a byte object which we send back to the server and then we decrypt there.
                img = ImageGrab.grab()

                bytes_img = img.tobytes()

                # Send that we have taken a screenshot
                server.send("returnedScreenshot".encode("utf-8"))

                # Send the screenshot over.
                server.send(bytes_img)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Client(host='localhost', port=10000).start()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kaihan/PycharmProjects/Networking/demo/server.py", line 38, in <module>
    Server(host='localhost', port=10000).start()
  File "C:/Users/Kaihan/PycharmProjects/Networking/demo/server.py", line 32, in start
    img = Image.frombytes(data=screenshot, size=(500, 500), mode="RGB")
  File "C:\Users\Kaihan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2412, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "C:\Users\Kaihan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 815, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

Comment: There might be multiple problems here. Please post a complete code sample we can run if you'd like further help. Also include the error output.

Comment: Done, i'vve posted complete code sample and the error output

Answer (score 0):

In `Server.start` you do: `screenshot = client.recv(4096)`. But you can't be sure that:

- This will actually read exactly 4096 bytes
- The client sent exactly 4096 bytes or less

And that's exactly what `PIL` is telling you: "not enough image data", which means that you didn't *read* enough data.

You should make sure you read everything the client sent. Try replacing `screenshot = client.recv(4096)` with the following:

```
screenshot = b""
chunk = client.recv(4096)
while chunk:
    screenshot += chunk
    chunk = client.recv(4096)
```

Comment: it just keeps going and havent showed the image yet, i added a else statement to after the while loop so while chunk:
else: but the loop never ends

Comment: @Lol123abc, what's the size of the image? Are you sure the whole image is being sent? Does `chunk` change over time or does it get stuck at the same value?

Comment: I don't know the size of the image, I am sure the whole image is being sent and I have no idea if its changing over time but it prints a new byte object all the time.

Comment: While correct, there are more humongous problems with OP code:(

Comment: can you maybe help me correct the humongous problems @martin